# Get data by having the contact number in Swift?

Tags: swift, contacts

I have imported the contact details into my app from device. Now, I want to get the details like, is every contact is already connected or not in WhatsApp, WeChat, Facebook and line accounts of the user contact who is having my app.

Also how to get the mail details(sent and received) by using the contact number?

Is it possible to get the above details? If yes, please guide me.

Comment: It's user's privacy. I It's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can get the contact details, but you can´t get information about other applications and specially not mail details. You have your information in your application.

Don´t try to use any private API for this, your app will then violate on Apples App Store guidelines.

Comment: So, you are saying that there are no ways to implement my requirement, right?

Comment: There might be, but not any that Apple would approve. If you violate their rules Apple can remove your app from App Store and ban your developer account.